# Why do Kubernetes secrets have both a key and name?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm curious why Kubernetes secrets require both a key and a name. When I create a secret I typically use the same value for both so I'm confused as to why they're both necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a design flexibility as reusability.  If you want to use custom names at deployment time  you can change the secret key names. Also you reuse the secrets in other deployments with different keys